# Update xml innerText with similar tag (element) names

Tags: c#, xml, innertext

My issue is that i have an email element of max 3 occurence in my xml file as shown below:

```
<contact> 
<email>A</email> 
<email>B</email> 
<email>C</email> 
</contact>
```

When i tried to edit the 3 tags with the following code below,

```
xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = "D"; 
xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = "E"; 
xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = "F";
```

Only the first email is edited, there is the problem of overwriting because of same xml element name.

```
<contact> 
<email>F</email> 
<email>B</email> 
<email>C</email> 
</contact>
```

I tried `xnl[0]["email"][0].InnerText = "D";` for choosing the first email element name, But this did not work. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE: (with code)**

c# code:

```
        public String updateContact(Int32 getPhoneNumber, Int32 getWorkNumber, Int32 getMobileNumber, String photo, String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String dateOfBirth, Int32 home, Int32 work, Int32 mobile, String email1, String email2, String email3)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");

        XmlNodeList xnl = doc.SelectNodes("/contactBook/contact/phone[home='" + getPhoneNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[work='" + getWorkNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[mobile='" + getMobileNumber + "']/parent::* ");

        if (xnl.Count != 0)
        {
            xnl[0]["photo"].InnerText = photo;
            xnl[0]["firstName"].InnerText = firstName;
            xnl[0]["lastName"].InnerText = lastName;
            xnl[0]["gender"].InnerText = gender;
            xnl[0]["dateOfBirth"].InnerText = dateOfBirth;
            xnl[0]["phone"]["home"].InnerText = home.ToString();
            xnl[0]["phone"]["work"].InnerText = work.ToString();
            xnl[0]["phone"]["mobile"].InnerText = mobile.ToString();
            xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = email1;
            xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = email2;
            xnl[0]["email"].InnerText = email3;

        }

        doc.Save("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");

        return "Updated";
    }
```

xml code:

```
<contact>
<photo>profilepic/default.jpg</photo>
<firstName>Hender</firstName>
<lastName>Casio</lastName>
<gender>Female</gender>
<dateOfBirth>1985-04-23</dateOfBirth>
<phone>
  <home>4453278</home>
  <work>3451390</work>
  <mobile>54356635</mobile>
</phone>
<email>casio.hender@mail.com</email>
<email>heder@aol.com</email>
<email>hencasio@yahoo.com</email>
</contact>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
Even when you are getting multiple contacts returned in your `XmlNodeList` from your XPath query, you are just updating first node.

If you are sure that your XPath query should return one or no contact then you should use [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/FCrVQO).

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");

XmlNode xn = doc.SelectSingleNode("/contactBook/contact/phone[home='" + getPhoneNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[work='" + getWorkNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[mobile='" + getMobileNumber + "']/parent::* ");

if (xn != null)
{
     xn["photo"].InnerText = photo;
     xn["firstName"].InnerText = firstName;
     xn["lastName"].InnerText = lastName;
     xn["gender"].InnerText = gender;
     xn["dateOfBirth"].InnerText = dateOfBirth;
     xn["phone"]["home"].InnerText = home.ToString();
     xn["phone"]["work"].InnerText = work.ToString();
     xn["phone"]["mobile"].InnerText = mobile.ToString();

     XmlNodeList xnl = xn.SelectNodes("email");
     xnl[0].InnerText = email1;
     xnl[1].InnerText = email2;
     xnl[2].InnerText = email3;
}

doc.Save("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");
return "Updated";
```

**UPDATE**: (**Solution 2**) In case multiple results are returned from your XPath query:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");

XmlNodeList xnl = doc.SelectNodes("/contactBook/contact/phone[home='" + getPhoneNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[work='" + getWorkNumber + "']/parent::* | /contactBook/contact/phone[mobile='" + getMobileNumber + "']/parent::* ");

foreach(XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
     xn["photo"].InnerText = photo;
     xn["firstName"].InnerText = firstName;
     xn["lastName"].InnerText = lastName;
     xn["gender"].InnerText = gender;
     xn["dateOfBirth"].InnerText = dateOfBirth;
     xn["phone"]["home"].InnerText = home.ToString();
     xn["phone"]["work"].InnerText = work.ToString();
     xn["phone"]["mobile"].InnerText = mobile.ToString();

     XmlNodeList xnlElement = xn.SelectNodes("email");
     xnlElement[0].InnerText = email1;
     xnlElement[1].InnerText = email2;
     xnlElement[2].InnerText = email3;
}

doc.Save("xmlFile/xml/myContactBook/src/myContactBook.xml");
return "Updated";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry Hassan Nisar, I was perhaps not enough clear on my code. I have now edited the original post. How can i search back again in an XmlNodeList? Is it possible?

Comment: XmlNodeList represents an ordered collection of nodes. You can traverse through XmlNodeList using loop. If you are sure that one result will be returned then you can use `SelectSingleNode`.

Comment: I have tried it but there seems to be a problem with the XmlNodeList, it is not actually searching in the XmlNode got from the XPath query. The other values ex:photo,firstname,etc.. are being updated to the XmlNode searched by the XPath. But it's only the email which is updating outside it; in the first contact element tag.

Comment: what is happening with email node? Still only first node getting update? Can you update your question.

Comment: I have updated the original post by adding the code of xml. can you have a look. thanks

Comment: Code I mentioned above should work. Root element of your XML is `contactBook` which further contains `contact` elements.

Comment: Please use code mentioned in answer inside `updateContact` method.

Comment: Also please let me know one important question. Your search result brings multiple result or just one?? If more than one elements are returned then I can change code in solution2. Please wait for my update.

Comment: I have tried the code in the updateContact Method but still the same problem as posted above. The search should return the first found contact. updating only 1 contact at a time. Thanks for helping

Comment: In case you have multiple results. You can use `XmlNodeList` but still you will be updating same values for all contacts. You got issue then.

Comment: Ok @JonathanLam I think both solutions should work. The `XPath` was mistakenly using `//email` instead of `email`. Can you tell results after using updated answer?

Comment: I have tried it but still the same problem persists :/

Comment: I have tested it and it is working for me. If second contact is the result then email nodes of that element are updated.

Comment: I dont know where is the mistake on my side. I have even copied paste the complete code, I will try to battle with it. Thanks

Comment: Yep, i think the error is on my side, perhaps its because am using .net framework 3.5